# Efficiently adding images to posts

Tags: support

When uploading a screenshot is there anyway to blow it up or somewhere to put it so viewers can see the full size of the image, as some of the detail may be obscured when shrunk down to fit the question box. thank you.

Comment: Normally, we can just open it in a new tab etc. You don't need to worry about this, as long as your original image has a decent resolution.

Comment: If you use an HTML `<img>`, you can enclose it within an anchor tag `<a>` to point it to the image. Make sure you upload it the normal way, first.

Comment: The only way to do this is with javascript or css, and it's not possible to include either in the answers. Unless this feature was added by website administrators, it's not possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right clicking and opening in a new tab is the usual way to do this. You can also make a copy of the autogenerated image link, and then encapsulate the image markup in link markup, using the image link as your destination URL.

Answer (score 8):

Expanding on Roland's answer, you can accomplish that with the following Markdown:

```
[![Click for Larger Version](http://example.com/img.jpg)](http://example.com/img.jpg)
```

**Example:**

[image: Click for Larger Version]